# Accessing return value from getter and setter in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to access a return value in a getter and use it in a conditional statement to disable a feature. I will organize the code below so you get a better understanding of what is going on since the value is being passed to a interface. I have declared the function inside fixture controller because there is a global variable that the function uses so I then pass the value into a set method into the Interface and both classes extend the interface and use each others methods. I have implemented the set method in the fixtureReport class but I am having issues accessing the value I assign to the function call.

I need the return value to use it in a another function within the fixture report class.

```
public Interface FixtureView{
    // adding function to interface so fixture report can access
    void setReceiverType(Boolean receiver);
}
```

```
public class fixtureController : FixtureView {
    // global variable which the get receivertype method needs 
    scConfig config;
    
    public bool getReceiverType(){
        int receiver = getValue();

        if(receiver == nanoReceiver)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
}
```

```
public partial class fixtureReport : FixtureView{

public void setReceiverType(bool receiver){
    fixtureController receiverType = new fixtureController();
    
    // I am storing the function call getReceiverType in a variable here so I can 
    // use it in this file in a different function but I am unable to access. It does 
    // not show up in the autofill menu when I start type the variable name
    receiver = receiverType.getReceiverType();
}
```

Ive tried to set the function equal to a variable so it would be easier to manipulate but that didnt work and I tried to just make the function call in the set method but didnt quite understand that.

Comment: We don't write `getXXX()` and `setXXX()` methods in C#. Instead, we declare a **property** with `get` and `set` sections.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Yeah I saw that once I posted it and I didnt do a great job at paraphrasing my problem! I will do a better job and since I will be using stack overflow more often, I will get better at it! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are looking for `event`s? Let's design the interface as

```
public interface IFixtureView {
  // The property itself 
  // I have declared it of type "bool" but you may actually want "int"
  //TODO: Find a better name: "ReceiverType" == "true" is misleading
  public bool ReceiverType { get; set; }
  // Event when ReceiverType is changed
  public event EventHandler ReceiverTypeChanged;
}
```

The implementation can be as follow:

```
public class FixtureController : IFixtureView {
  // Backing field with default value
  private bool m_ReceiverType = false;

  // ReceiverType property which is based on the backing field
  public bool ReceiverType {
    get => m_ReceiverType; 
    set {
      // are we really changing m_ReceiverType?
      if (value == m_ReceiverType)
        return;

      // If yes, assign
      m_ReceiverType = value;

      // and let all subscribers know that state is changed
      ReceiverTypeChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
  }

  public event EventHandler ReceiverTypeChanged;
}
```

Usage:

```
FixtureController controller = new FixtureController();

controller.ReceiverTypeChanged += (s, e) => {
  FixtureController ctrl = s as FixtureController;

  Console.WriteLine($"State is changed, now it's {ctrl.ReceiverType}");
}

...

// When we change the state
// ReceiverTypeChanged will be fired
// And we'll see "State is changed, now it's ..."
controller.ReceiverType = !ReceiverType;
```

Comment: Thank you for providing great feedback! I cant post everything in my code since its for a defense company so I tried to paraphrase to get my point across. You answered my issue and code is working now.

Comment: @vishalpatel: I am not looking for your *actual code* (which can be top secret), *made up* one is OK when it clearly shows the problem you are facing.

Comment: Yes I understand and I didnt do the best job at getting my point across which I will work on so my problem can be understood! Thank you!